# Using another forms event procedure

Tags: delphi, events, tform

Is there any way to allow one form to use the event procedures from another form?

E.g. I have a form called PongForm and another called ObstPongForm. There is a ticker on PongForm and another one on ObstPongForm. Is it possible to get ObstPongForm to use the code from PongForm's 'tick' event in it's own 'tick' event? Maybe by letting ObstPongForm inherit from PongForm?

Comment: You can, but it would be better style to have both of the forms call another class that implements the logic used by both. If you're writing all your program logic in your OnTimer event handler, you're heading down a bad road that many delphi programmers take years to realize was a bad idea.

Comment: @warren I think you should write this up as an answer. It is the right answer in my view.

Comment: @David I pretty much wrote that in my answer, but no one seems to like it for some reason

Comment: @daniel I think that's because that message is buried in the final paragraph. I'd upvote a short answer saying just what warren said and no more!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simply assign it by code (as long as you have access to both instances):

```
ObstPongForm.Ticker.OnTick := PongForm.TickerTick;
```

Comment: Just note that when `ObstPongForm.Ticker.OnTick` fires, the `Self` variable in `TickerTick` will be `PongForm`, not `ObstPongForm`.

Comment: If the OnTick events and handlers are declared as `published`, you can even do this assignment at design-time instead of in code, as long as ObstPongForm has PongForm included in its `uses` clause.

Comment: Boy I really hope that ObstPongForm is destroyed before PongForm!

Comment: @Warren, I only gave an answer to the question - I didn't make a comment on the design (if any).

Comment: I think it's helpful to point out reasons why (especially with wm_timer messages) it's a bad idea to connect a method of an object with a different lifetime to another object that contains a wm_timer event handler.

Answer (score 2):

It would be better style to have both of the forms call another class that implements the logic used by both. If you're writing all your program logic in your OnTimer event handler, you're heading down a bad road that many delphi programmers take years to realize was a bad idea

So one form needs to call your method, it does it like this:

```
procedure TForm1.DoSomething;
begin
    DataModule1.LogicMethod;
end;
```

Elsewhere there is a timer...

```
procedure TForm2.Timer1Timer(Sender:TObject);
begin
    DataModule1.LogicMethod;
end;
```

And then the method itself:

```
procedure TDataModule1.LogicMethod;
begin
   // Everything that you used to have in Timer1Timer goes here, except the setting of
   // UI properties in Form1 which is kept in Form1:
   Inc(FCounter);// stupid example.

   //
   if Assigned(FOnResults) then
   FOnResults(Self,  FCounter, FDataObject1); 
      // Form2 is connected to FOnResults event, and stores the 
      // result in the UI somewhere.
end;
```

Comment: As requested, this comment is now an answer. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Event handlers are just normal procedures.  If your ObstPongForm tick handler has additional code that it needs to run in addition to the PongForm's code, then you can call the PongForm's tick handler manually when needed, eg:

```
uses
  ..., PongForm;

procedure ObstPongForm.TickHandler(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ...
  PongForm.TickHandler(Self);
  ...
end;
```

Comment: I would do it like this: `if Assigned(PongForm) then PongForm.TickHandler(Self)`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, forms are just classes like any other, and Delphi supports visual inheritance, so you can call inherited methods normally.

If ObstPongForm is a specialized version of PongForm then inheritance makes sense, but be careful as ObstPongForm will inherit all visual controls from the PongForm, including whatever you may add in the future.

Also since I assume you already have both forms, making one inherit from another is doable but requires some manual DFM editing, mainly changing the

`Object ObstPongForm: TObstPongForm`
 to
`Inherited ObstPongForm: TObstPongForm`

If the code you want to reuse may be needed in several unrelated forms, then moving the code to a common unit used by these forms may be the best solution